# How can I convert JavaScript float PCM audio array to little endian byte string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, audio, pcm, endianness

I want to convert an audio float array to a byte string in JavaScript. With the conversion to bytes, I am expecting a two digit number, then I can then append to a string, see the output of this example:

```
Input: [0.0007124987314455211, 0.0005752402357757092, -0.0010658394312486053, -0.0004562278045341372 ,...]
Output: '\x02\x04\x35...'
```

But I am getting 4 digit numbers. How can I convert to bytes correctly?

```
function floatToByteString(input){
  //first convert to 16 bit int array
  var intarray = new Int16Array(input.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    var s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, input[i]));
    var newint = s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7FFF;
    intarray[i] = newint;
  }

  //second: convert 16 bit int array to little endian byte string
  var bytestring = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    var thisint = intarray[i]
    var bytel = thisint & 0xff;
    var byteb = (thisint >> 8) & 0xff;
    bytestring += "\\x"+bytel + "" + byteb
  }

  return bytestring;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to generate very large strings this way, containing lots of unnecessary data. If it absolutely must be a string, base64 would be better. Also, your temporary int array is going to use unnecessary memory and slow things down.

16-bit values generate 4-digit hex values. So isn't 4-digit numbers what you want?